# ActiveXObject Number of rows counter

Tags: javascript, excel

I have this piece of code:

```
    function GetData(evt){
        var adresses = new Array();
        var j = 0;
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var fil = document.getElementById("file");
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(fil.value);
        var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets(1);

        for(var i=2;i<500;i++){
            var morada = excel_sheet.Range("E"+ i );
            var localidade = excel_sheet.Range("C"+ i );
            var pais = excel_sheet.Range("A"+i);
            adresses[j] = (morada + ", " + localidade + ", " + pais);
            j++;
        }
        for(var k = 0; k<j; k++) {
            codeAddress(adresses[k]);
        }
    }
```

It receives an excel file and processes the data like I want. The thing is, it is very hard coded.

For instant, in this for:

```
for(var i=2;i<500;i++)
```

I am using 500, but I would like to use the number of rows in the sheet. I have already tried a few things like rows.count and whatever and I gave some alerts to see the results, but I just can't find the one who tells me the number of rows.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :

```
excel_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Does it works ?

Comment: Unable to get property "Rows" of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Are you sure that your excel_sheet is correctly open ?
Because if I refer to this documents : 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1855932.aspx?The+value+of+the+property+ReadExcel+is+null+or+undefined+
Or this one : 
http://nimblecoder.com/blog/archive/2007/04/25/Scripting-Excel-with-Javascript.aspx

Seems to be the right thing to do :)

Comment: I can read all the contect correctly. So I am guessing it is.

Comment: In the links, I can see the following code :

excel.worksheets(n).select(); 
var excelSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
excelSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

It is maybe the select method ? :)

Comment: It doesn't work because excel is the Application object. You need to change excel to excel_sheet.